# How to detect break during yield

Tags: ruby, ffi

For a gem I intend to publish, I want to create an enumerable interface wrapping an external library. (Called via FFI)

I have this code (stripped for clarity)

```rb
def each_shape(&block)
  callback = lambda do |*args|
    yield
  end
  cpSpaceEachShape(callback) # FFI function, calls callback
end
```

which is called with a block like this

```rb
space.each_shape do
# ...
end

cpSpaceStep() # Other FFI function
```

The `cpSpaceEachShape` is an external C library function, which in returns calls `callback` a number of times (synchronously, no way to cancel it)

This works great, until I use `break` in the top-level block, like this:

```rb
space.each_shape do
  break
end

cpSpaceStep() # Error from C library because iteration is still running
```

I'm not sure how Ruby, FFI and the C library are interacting here. From the Ruby perspective it looks like the `break` "jumps" out of the top-level block, the callback block, from `cbSpaceEachShape` and out of `each_shape`.

Side question: What happens here from a low-level perspective, e.g. what happens to the stack?

Main question: **Can I capture the `break` from the top-level block?**

I was hoping for something like this: (not working, pseudo code)

```rb
def each_shape(&block)
  @each_shape_cancelled = false
  callback = lambda do |*args|
    yield unless @each_shape_cancelled
  rescue StopIteration
    @each_shape_cancelled = true
  end
  cpSpaceEachShape(callback)
end
```

**EDIT:** This is for a gem I intend to publish. I want my users to be able to use regular Ruby. If they were required to use `throw`... How would they know...? If there is no good solution I will - begrudgingly - construct an array beforehand and collect/cache all callbacks before yielding its contents.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `throw` and `catch` which is another control flow that lets you break out deeply nested contexts. https://avdi.codes/throw-catch-raise-rescue-im-so-confused/

Comment: @max: Thank you, I think it would work, too, but it would not be very user-friendly. Updated my question.

Comment: _"Error from C library because iteration is still running"_ – what kind of error is that? Furthermore, what do you expect that `break` to do? Stop the iteration? Or be ignored and just not cause an error?

Comment: @DanielRikowski what do you mean by user friendly? That depends entirely on what you actually do with the low level tool provided.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around that `yield block` – are you yielding the block to itself? (like `block.call(block)`) Can you explain how the code works what what the callback / lambda is about?

Comment: @Stefan It's an assertion error from the library author: a console message and then a call to `abort` (the C function) ( https://github.com/slembcke/Chipmunk2D/blob/edf83e5603c5a0a104996bd816fca6d3facedd6a/include/chipmunk/chipmunk_private.h#L273-L277 ) No error from the library is my primary concern. Since there's no way to stop the callbacks, my plan is to still receive them, but no longer forwarding them via `yield`

Comment: @Stefan: A stupid mistake when simplifying the code, originally there was a commented `# block.call` there, too, which somehow slipped in the `yield` line while editing it in the browser. Sorry!

Comment: @max: My idea was this: If I provide a Ruby interface for a C library, that interface should behave like Ruby. And since the usual way of breaking out of an simple enumeration is to call `break` it would be very surprising having to use a `throw` instead. Should that in fact be the only alternative, I'd rather remove this function, or at least rename it, so that it no longer promises "`each`-like" semantics